# Cannot Write to a file in PHP

Tags: php, file

I am trying to write a simple text into a php file.
The snap of the code is below:

```
$a =  $_GET["option"];
$a = (string)$a;
$b = $_GET["ip_address"];
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile,$a);
fwrite($myfile,$b);
echo $a;
echo $b;
```

When I open the file through the terminal , its empty. however the echo commands in the php code display output as expected.

Should the file retain the content after the program has finished execution ?
I am using syntax from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp)

EDIT:
The new file is created by PHP however it does not have write permissions. I changed it. It works now

Comment: You need to close the file after using it. Use fclose() to do that

Comment: In your case, I would recommend using `file_put_contents()` instead of `fopen()` since you want to write and then append the data.

Answer (score 3):

```
$a =  $_GET["option"];
$a = (string)$a;
$b = $_GET["ip_address"];
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile,$a);
fwrite($myfile,$b);
fclose($myfile);
echo $a;
echo $b;
```

try this once, as you were not closing the connection, thus the output was not getting stored

Comment: Please explain (for OP and future users) what you are doing here, instead of posting a code-only answer.

Answer (score 1):

use `fclose($myfile);` to close the file and check the permission of the file/folder in which you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

you should must be close the connection. please read this manual [fclose manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile,"some text");
fwrite($myfile,"another text");
fclose($myfile);
echo $a;
echo $b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answers saying you must use `fclose` do solve your problem, this is incidental. The actual issue is when you use `fwrite` the output is *buffered* - it's stored in memory but not yet committed to the filesystem. In order to commit this output to your file you should use `fflush($myfile)` ([fflush documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php)); you can do this multiple times before closing your file handle. Do bear in mind you should always close file handles with `fclose` to ensure resources are cleaned up correctly.